# SQL select from table where quantity is not negative

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do I do select * from salesorder where quantity is only a positive number? (i want to exclude orders with negative order quantities...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
select * from salesorder where quantity >= 0
```

Comment: oh yea duh!  can tell i'm not getting enough sleep ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
select * from salesorder where quantity !< 0
```

`!<` means not smaller than(simply it means greater than!)